# co-existence of wifi & bluetooth pan connection

Tags: android, bluetooth, wifi

can bluetooth-pan & wifi connection coexist in android device,i have setup a linux box which sends  data to my android device over bluetooth using PAN profile & i need to access internet on my android device at the same time.

As soon as i turn on wifi on my android device the bluetooth PAN connection between linux box & my android device breaks
as default route gets updated to wlan

```
root@matissewifiue:/ # ip route
default via 10.0.4.254 dev wlan0  metric 325
10.0.4.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.4.172  metric 325
192.19.253.0/24 dev bt-pan  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.19.253.1
root@matissewifiue:/ #
```

Is it possible to have both connection work in parallel ?

Comment: I'm looking for the same answer, any luck yet? @Himanshu?

Comment: Unfortunately the Android framework only allows one internet based connection , either wi-fi or bluetooth PAN.I believe this behavior can be  modified in a rooted android device.Since our use case needed non-rooted Android device , we had to reject this approach.

Comment: It has to be a way to tell android that if a request to http://193.39.3.3 is made to use interface bt0 for example, there is a way in linux I think it should be a way in Android SDK we just have to figure it out.

Comment: Check this out @Himanshu https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/07/connecting-your-app-to-wi-fi-device.html